# Is there any free software alternative to CCS C compiler?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded, microcontroller, firmware

Is there any free software alternative to CCS C compiler?

Please also send the links and state the pros and cons if you already had an experience using them.

Comment: You might want to link CCS compiler to a good description...

Comment: http://www.ccsinfo.com a compiler for Microchip

Comment: @Kenny: Do you know that or is that a guess?  It could as likely be Code Composer Studio (http://focus.ti.com/dsp/docs/dspsupportatn.tsp?familyId=44&sectionId=3&tabId=415&toolTypeId=30). @Lemuel needs to be far more explicit.  The best thing to do is specify exactly what processor he wishes to generate code for.

Comment: @Clifford, yeah a guess based on that thet tagged it firmware/microcontroller, but if TI gave theirs the same initials....maybe a bad guess.

Comment: @kenny: I would say it was probably the right guess, but it is by no means a given; the comment was really aimed at getting clarification from @Lemuel, and improving the quality and precision of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's SDCC http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/ and the Microchip compiler itself is free for student/hobby projects too.

I have never used SDCC and it seems to be a bit raw from what I've read.

The Microchip C compiler works fine and is more true to the C standard than CCS.

But I prefer CCS's wrapper around the API. And it's not to expensive.

Given that I work on non-hobby projects for the PIC, I'm stuck with CCS for now, warts and all.

Answer (score 2):

tech C is now owned by microchip and the lite version is free.  dont know how it compares but worth trying at that price.